# Medium trust large file upload in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, stream

I need large file upload support in my hosted (godaddy) medium trust asp.net app.
It obviously needs to be responsive with indication of progress, so handling the stream myself is important.

This all seems pretty simple and works well when in full trust:
1.Write an HttpModule that listens for file uploads.
2.Get the HttpWorkerRequest object from the Context using reflection.
3.Write out stream to a FileStream

All very well and good except that I keep getting permission exceptions when trying to get the HttpWorkerRequest object from the context in medium trust. Whether I use reflection or I use System.IServiceProvider.GetService() to get the object (which is clearly using reflection), I get the same error.

I have also tried using System.Web.HttpPostedFile. It has a property InputStream. But it seems this object is uploading the entire file on initialization, so no good.

I have googled myself tired, and can't find another alternative.

Even if it is a security risk to let users have the HttpWorkerRequest object, surely the framework provides another way to handle the stream of files when Method="POST" and enctype="multipart/form-data"

Any ideas would be great
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also try reading from `context.Request.InputStream`.

Comment: I gave this a shot. The moment i tried to Read() from the stream, the browser uploaded the entire file. So it kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: @slightlyannoyed, how are you reading the stream? You shouldn't load the entire stream into a buffer. You need to read it in chunks and immediately write the chunks to another stream (for example a file stream).

Comment: Yep. I am reading in chunks. 4096 bytes at a time to be specific. Calling the Read() method seems to do its job as far as feeding me chunk by chunk goes. But before it returns that first chunk the framework fetches the entire file from the browser without my consent. Make sense?